# Emacs/auctex not asking for prompting label anymore

Tags: emacs, latex, auctex, aquamacs

I know that the default mode of Auctex is that prompting c-c c-e equation RET is supposed to ask me to prompt a label, unless I modify purposely the reftex-plug-into-AUCTeX value.

I find myself in a situation where, after installing the last version of aquamacs (on a new config), I am not asked anymore to prompt a label, which is assigned by default to some eq:N value.

I'd like to have this very convenient prompting feature back, any idea where I should look for ?

Comment: Read the documentation of `reftex-insert-label-flags`.

Comment: Thanks a lot ! For some reason it was badly configured.